# Convert LINQ in query syntax to lambda syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

This is my LINQ query, Please help me in changing this LINQ query to query using Lambda expression:

```
var query = from d in db.customers
            from s in db.tbl_states
            where d.cust_state == s.state_id
            select new
            {
                d.cust_name,
                s.state_name
            };
```

Comment: you're about to use the `inner join` but you have no foreign key to relate the one table

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var query =
    db.customers.Join (         
        db.tbl_states,        
        d => d.cust_state,       
        s => s.state_id,   
        (d, s) => new { d.cust_name, s.state_name }
    );
```

Comment: Getting an error:"The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TOuter,TKey>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TInner,TKey>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: @user1993853 this should work properly, please ensure that the query itself works fine. Where does you get this exception from?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var query = db.customers.Join(db.tbl_states, d => d.cust_state, s => s.state_id, (d, s) => new { d.cust_name, s.state_name });
```

Comment: Getting Error:-"The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TOuter,TKey>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TInner,TKey>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: Are cust_state and state_id the same type? If not they need to be, your original query wouldn't have worked either though.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your `linq` its should be like this

```
var query = from d in db.customers
            join s in db.tbl_states on d.cust_state equals s.state_id
            select new
            {
                d.cust_name,
                s.state_name
            };
```

for `Lambda`

```
var list = db.customers                     
.Join(db.tbl_states, 
      s => s.tbl_states, 
      d => d.state_id, 
      (s, d) => new                                                                                         
                 {
                     d.cust_name,
                     s.state_name
                 });
```